Can I set Severity level of CS0535 in C# to suggested
My Problem is, that in my cleanUp is the fix warning/erros from editorconfig. But it also auto fixes the CS0535. But I don't want that to happen. How can I silent the error and get the fix as a suggestion but still throw an error when I build the application?
I've already tried:
dotnet_diagnostic.CS0535.severity = suggested

But it doesn't work.

What is cleanUp? How do you call it?

CleanUp is the codeCleanup from Visual Studio, there i have the "fix analyzer warnings and erros set in EditorConfig" configured.

CS0535 is a compiler diagnosis which cannot be configured by the .editorconfig file.

oh,ok. thanks :)

The Microsoft Official documentation for CS0535 starts with the following title in great big huge letters:
Compiler Error CS0535
 
So, this is a compiler error, not a warning.
The difference between warnings and errors is that warnings can be suppressed, but errors cannot be suppressed; they absolutely have to be fixed.
